# OpenMeetings Service failed and no response was returned

Tags: php, moodle, red5, openmeetings

I'm trying to connect Apache OpenMeetings V3.1.1 to PHP Moodle CMS V2.9.7 
OpenMeetings is installed and run successfully, I can login to openmeetings admin using the username/password I've set during the installation.

When I'm trying to add a new openmeetings session from moodle I'm getting this error:

```
array (
'url' => 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5080/openmeetings/services/user/login?&user=administrator&pass=password',
'content_type' => NULL,
'http_code' => 0,
'header_size' => 0,
'request_size' => 0,
'filetime' => -1,
'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
'redirect_count' => 0,
'total_time' => 0,
'namelookup_time' => 0.00031599999999999998,
'connect_time' => 0,
'pretransfer_time' => 0,
'size_upload' => 0,
'size_download' => 0,
'speed_download' => 0,
'speed_upload' => 0,
'download_content_length' => -1,
'upload_content_length' => -1,
'starttransfer_time' => 0,
'redirect_time' => 0,
'certinfo' => 
array (
),
'primary_ip' => 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx',
'redirect_url' => '',
```

)

I'm using the same openmeetings username/password in moodle plugin configuration.

This user has all permissions: `[Admin, Dashboard, Login, Room, Soap]`

So Could anyone tell me how can I fix this or how can I troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct url : `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5080/openmeetings/services/user/login?&user=administrator&pass=password` ?

I dont think there should be `&` between `/login?` and `user`.

Comment: @BhushanPatil that URL generated automatically by moodle plugin

Comment: Try to call this url from browser, with and without that extra `&` and check if you can get session

Comment: @BhushanPatil it works, and returned json with success message

Comment: @BhushanPatil / Ashraf : I am having the same issue but on hitting http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/services/user/login?&user=admin&pass=password, i am not getting json it is saying "This site can’t be reached" "localhost refused to connect.",, any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, 
The issue was that I've installed openmeetings on an external server. So I have to open the `incoming & outgoing` for `port 5080` on both servers `openmeeting server and the application server`

Comment: If you can't open port 5080 (for example on a shared host) you can change the port config on the Openmeetings server to be on port 80